# Please show that I've voted for a tag synonym in my suggested view

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-synonyms, information-display

Since it's so onerous to go vote on a tag-synonym, violating the rule of *least-number-of-clicks-wins*, could we **please have the suggested view show that I've already voted on a tag**, so that I don't have to click into it, then click on the up/downvote to see if I have or not.  Then you have to go back to the page, and click on the next one, and so on.